# LaTeX reserving space for undrawn coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates, tikz-pic, calc

I'm trying to write a function to ease the drawing of figures. I called this function `\drawcurve` as is shown below. It's purpose is to create a curve between 2 lines indicated by coordinates in it's arguments. It looks like this:
`\drawcurve{<line1_co1>}{<line1_co2>}{<line2_co1>}{<line2_co2>}{<curve settings>}`

I'm however stumbling on the problem that due to my definition for coordinate v1 and v2, the tikz library also reserves space on the figure for these undrawn coordinates causing my figure to be lobsided. Up until now, I haven't been able to figure out how to make either tikz not reserve space for these coordinates or avoid using the coordinate definition altogether. How can I achieve this?

The code of the figure I'm making is also included. The problem doesn't seem extremely bad in this case, but as I would like to use the command `\drawcurve` often during my Thesis, it needs to work in every circumstance.

I hope my question is clear.
Thanks!

```
\newcommand{\drawcurve}[5]{
            \draw
            #1 coordinate (start_far)
            #2 coordinate (start_close)
            ($(start_close) - (start_far)$) coordinate (v1)
            #3 coordinate (end_close)
            #4 coordinate (end_far)
            ($(end_close) - (end_far)$) coordinate (v2)
            ;

            \draw 
            let \p1=(v1), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
            let \p2=(v2), \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} in
            [#5] (start_close) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (end_close)
            ;
}
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % AXES
      \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {$A[\qty{}{\decibel}]$};
      \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (8, 0) node[right] {$f [\qty{}{\hertz}]$};

    % DRAW DOTTED LINES
        \draw[dotted, thick] (8,3) -- (0, 3);
        \draw[dotted, thick] (4,0) -- (4, 4);

    % DRAW CURVES
        \draw[color=blue, ultra thick] (0,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5);
        \drawcurve{(0,3.5)}{(3.5,3.5)}{(5,2.5)}{(6.5,1)}{color=blue, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=blue, ultra thick] (5,2.5) -- (6.5,1);

        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (0,2.5) -- (3.5,2.5);
        \drawcurve{(0,2.5)}{(3.5,2.5)}{(5,3.5)}{(5.5,4)}{color=red, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (5,3.5) -- (5.5,4);
        \drawcurve{(5,3.5)}{(5.5,4)}{(6.5,4)}{(8,2.5)}{color=red, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (6.5,4) -- (8,2.5);

        \draw[color=green, ultra thick] (0,3) -- (5.5,3);
        \drawcurve{(0,3)}{(5.5,3)}{(7,2)}{(8,1)}{color=green, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=green, ultra thick] (7,2) -- (8,1);
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the best solution, but you could add the option `overlay` to the first `\draw` macro in your custom command (which should probably rather be just a `\path` since you don't want to draw anything with it). This will prevent this path from adding to the current bounding box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the option `overlay` to the path in your custom macro where you define the coordinates. This way, this path won't add to the bounding box of the picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\drawcurve}[5]{
    \path[overlay]
        #1 coordinate (start_far)
        #2 coordinate (start_close)
        ($(start_close) - (start_far)$) coordinate (v1)
        #3 coordinate (end_close)
        #4 coordinate (end_far)
        ($(end_close) - (end_far)$) coordinate (v2)
    ;

    \draw
        let \p1=(v1), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
        let \p2=(v2), \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)} in
        [#5] (start_close) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (end_close)
    ;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % AXES
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {$A[\qty{}{\decibel}]$};
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (8, 0) node[right] {$f [\qty{}{\hertz}]$};

    % DRAW DOTTED LINES
        \draw[dotted, thick] (8,3) -- (0, 3);
        \draw[dotted, thick] (4,0) -- (4, 4);

    % DRAW CURVES
        \draw[color=blue, ultra thick] (0,3.5) -- (3.5,3.5);
        \drawcurve{(0,3.5)}{(3.5,3.5)}{(5,2.5)}{(6.5,1)}{color=blue, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=blue, ultra thick] (5,2.5) -- (6.5,1);

        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (0,2.5) -- (3.5,2.5);
        \drawcurve{(0,2.5)}{(3.5,2.5)}{(5,3.5)}{(5.5,4)}{color=red, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (5,3.5) -- (5.5,4);
        \drawcurve{(5,3.5)}{(5.5,4)}{(6.5,4)}{(8,2.5)}{color=red, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (6.5,4) -- (8,2.5);

        \draw[color=green, ultra thick] (0,3) -- (5.5,3);
        \drawcurve{(0,3)}{(5.5,3)}{(7,2)}{(8,1)}{color=green, ultra thick}
        \draw[color=green, ultra thick] (7,2) -- (8,1);
      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]